# Why does fail2ban not trigger my custom filter?

Tags: linux, regular-expression, logs, fail2ban

`fail2ban-regex` verified that my filter matches `Jan 14 07:39:41 myhost01 sshd[26433]: Connection closed by authenticating user root 127.0.0.1 port 56216 [preauth]` 68 times inside `auth.log`, but `fail2ban-client status sshd-preauth` shows 0 matched filters and actions. What might I be missing?

jail.d/custom.local

```
[sshd-preauth]

enabled = true
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
backend = auto
banaction = disable-user
maxretry = 1
findtime = 1m
filter  = sshd-preauth
```

filter.d/sshd-preauth.conf

```
[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf

[DEFAULT]

_daemon = sshd
__pref = (?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?
__suff = (?: \[preauth\])?\s*
__on_port_opt = (?: port \d+)?(?: on \S+(?: port \d+)?)?
__alg_match = (?:(?:\w+ (?!found\b)){0,2}\w+)

[Definition]
prefregex = ^<F-MLFID>%(__prefix_line)s</F-MLFID>%(__pref)s<F-CONTENT>.+</F-CONTENT>$
failregex = ^Connection closed by authenticating user root (?P<ip4>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}) port \d+ \[preauth\]$
datepattern = {^LN-BEG}
```

action.d/disable-user.conf

```
[Definition]
actionstart = touch /tmp/01234
actionstop =
actioncheck = 
actionban = touch /tmp/OSSEC
actionunban = touch /tmp/UNBAN
```

fail2ban-regex

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/auth.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd-preauth.conf  

Running tests

Use   failregex filter file : sshd-preauth, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use      datepattern : Default Detectors
Use         log file : /var/log/auth.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results

Failregex: 68 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [68] ^Connection closed by authenticating user root (?P<ip4>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}) port \d+ \[preauth\]$
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [865] {^LN-BEG}(?:DAY )?MON Day %k:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: ExYear)?
`-

Lines: 865 lines, 0 ignored, 68 matched, 797 missed
[processed in 0.06 sec]

Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 797 lines
```

#### UPDATE

Fail2ban filter is triggered if I `ssh` from LAN and not from localhost to the computer. So apparently `fail2ban` ignores localhost logs, even though I configured `jail.conf` to check for localhost too:

`jail.conf`

```
[DEFAULT] 
ignorself = false
ignoreip =
```

Is this a known limitation for fail2ban or is there a workaround?

#### Update 2 (Solution)

There are two bugs in fail2ban. The config variable should be ignoreself not ignorself. Also release < v0.10.3 have a bug. With the newest fail2ban release it works fine now.

Comment: What is `PermitRootLogin` set to in your `sshd_config`?

Comment: I get that failed `ssh` access on root from localhost are result from your tests, I would look if `fail2ban` or `iptables` can handle `lo0` interface.

Comment: @ErikF `PermitRootLogin` is set to `prohibit-password`.

Comment: @Archemar I triggered the failed `ssh` by entering a wrong ssh-key passphrase on purpose. `ssh` to localhost work fine, but I want to catch wrongly entered passphrases with fail2ban.

Comment: @Archemar Indeed it seems `ssh`-logs from `localhost` are ignored by `fail2ban`, even though I configured in `jail.conf`: `[DEFAULT] ignorself = false  ignoreip =`. Because when I just tried to `ssh` from LAN (not localhost) the filter is triggered just fine. Just from `localhost` it's not triggered. Any way to workaround this?

Comment: failed ssh attempt's log from LAN or localhost are on same place, my **guess** is that fail2ban won't ban on `lo0` ...

Comment: @Archemar It works now. There are two bugs in fail2ban. The config variable should be `ignoreself` not `ignorself`. Also release < v0.10.3 have a bug. With the newest fail2ban release it works fine now.

Comment: @fremon: I noticed that you seemed to have solved the problem with some guidance in the comments. Please consider posting the "solution" part of your question as an Answer. Thank you!